# Directory/Paths | can't get the right file path

Tags: php, directory, filepath

Note, inside my store.php I have `<?php include_once ("js.html"); ?>`

My directory map & file paths.

```
public
     |_css
     |_img
     |_include
     |       |_ajax
     |       |    |_username.php
     |       |_config.php               
     |       |_js.html
     |_items
     |_js
     |_slides
     |_store.php
```

here's my code in js.html

```
<script>
function ajax_username_check()
{
    var check_this=$("#username").val();
    $.post("include/ajax/username.php", {username : check_this}, function(email) {
    //code here
    })
}
</script>
```

here's my code in username.php

```
<?php
require_once('../include/config.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$user = new user($pdo);

    if(!$username == "")
    {
        $ok = $user->checkUsername($username);
        if($ok == true)
        {
            echo '1';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '0';
        }
    }
?>
```

I can't seem to get this right

```
require_once('../include/config.php');
```

I've tried `../config.php` , `../include/config.php`, `include/config.php`

**It worked when my files were like this:**

```
public
     |_css
     |_img
     |_include
     |       |_ajax
     |       |    
     |       |_config.php               
     |       |_js.html
     |_username.php
     |_items
     |_js
     |_slides
     |_store.php
```

js.html

```
<script>
function ajax_username_check()
{
    var check_this=$("#username").val();
    $.post("username.php", {username : check_this}, function(email) {
    //code here
    })
}
</script>
```

username.php

```
<?php
require_once('include/config.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$user = new user($pdo);

    if(!$username == "")
    {
        $ok = $user->checkUsername($username);
        if($ok == true)
        {
            echo '1';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '0';
        }
    }
?>
```

I've been stuck on this for a bit while reorganizing my folders, I can't tell if it's a simple mistake or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why not try with full real path? for example: /home/www/...

Comment: I tried `if(@require_once('127.0.0.1/include/config.php')) { echo '0' } else { echo '1' }` and it isn't working

Comment: `include/config.php` should work...

Comment: just tried, it didn't

Comment: ok use safest method, can you post full path of public?

Comment: I'm using local wamp server, public just gets replaced with www, or in this case `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: no, I am talking about file directory, nor the URL, for example: c:\xamp\htdocs\public

Comment: C:\wamp\www\include\ajax

Comment: then use this path for include for example: `include "C:\\wamp\\www\\include\\config.php"`

Comment: I've fixed it with `../../include/config.php` I don't understand though. why it has to go back two directories...

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick, I guess:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)  . '/../config.php');
```